# Why does catch in the calling function is never executed?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a simple use case that I want to execute a statement inside the catch blog inside catch block of calling function. Somehow in my code there is no execution of catch block statement inside calling function

```js
async function main() {

  try {
    console.log('jatin')
    const hello = await second()
    console.log(hello) //ok
    console.log('yes boy') //ok
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('cm') //not ok
    console.log(e) //not ok
  }
}

async function second() {
  try {
    console.log('in second') //ok
    throw new Error()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('trial') //ok
    console.log(error) //ok
    return error
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: You already caught the error in `second`.

Comment: Also, returning an error is not the same as `throw`ing it.

Comment: If you want to catch it again you should [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) it, not `return` it. No need for `new` of course, it already exists.

Comment: so what I do to catch that error in the main()

Comment: @JatinMehrotra rethrow it in second or don't catch at all in `second`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already caught the `Error` in the `second` function. If you want it to propagate back to the caller, you would need to rethrow it (or don't catch it in the first place).

```js
async function main() {
  try {
    console.log('main');
    const hello = await second();
    console.log(hello);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('catch block of main');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function second() {
  try {
    console.log('second');
    throw new Error();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('catch block of second');
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2):

An async function will only return a Promise that rejects if you have an *uncaught* `throw` (or if you return a `Promise.reject`). Because you're catching the Promise with your `catch` block and returning the error, the Promise returned by the function resolves to the value of the error (and does not *reject* with the value of the error).

Best approach to this sort of thing is to only catch at a level you can *actually handle* the error. If you can only do something sensible with it in `main`, then don't catch in `second`.

```js
async function main() {
  try {
    console.log('jatin')
    const hello = await second()
    console.log(hello) //ok
    console.log('yes boy') //ok
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('main catch')
  }
}

async function second() {
  console.log('in second') //ok
  throw new Error()
}

main()
```

If you *can* do something with it in `second` too, then `throw` after catching so that the Promise `second` returns rejects.

```js
async function main() {
  try {
    console.log('jatin')
    const hello = await second()
    console.log(hello) //ok
    console.log('yes boy') //ok
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('main caught')
  }
}

async function second() {
  try {
    console.log('in second') //ok
    throw new Error()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('trial') //ok
    console.log(error) //ok
    throw error;
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: I have to accept @Unmitigated answer as answer since he wrote first, but thank you for the explanation.